# Non-parametric bootstrapping on the highest level of clustered data using boot() function from {boot} in R

Tags: r, statistics, hierarchical-data, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I have two-level hierarchical data and I'm trying to perform non-parametric bootstrap sampling on the highest level, i.e., randomly sampling the highest-level clusters with replacement while keeping the original within-cluster data.

I want to achieve this using the boot() function in the {boot} package, for the reason that I then would like to build BCa confidence intervals using boot.ci() which requires a boot object.

Here follows my unlucky attempt - running a debug on the boot call showed that random sampling is not happening at cluster level (=subject).

```
### create a very simple two-level dataset with 'subject' as clustering variable

rho <- 0.4
dat <- expand.grid(
    trial=factor(1:5),
    subject=factor(1:3)
    )
sig <- rho * tcrossprod(model.matrix(~ 0 + subject, dat))
diag(sig) <- 1
set.seed(17); dat$value <- chol(sig) %*% rnorm(15, 0, 1)


### my statistic function (adapted from here: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/HowToBootstrapCorrelatedData)

resamp.mean <- function(data, i){
    cluster <- c('subject', 'trial')

    # sample the clustering factor
    cls <- unique(data[[cluster[1]]])[i]   

    # subset on the sampled clustering factors
    sub <- lapply(cls, function(b) subset(data, data[[cluster[1]]]==b))   

    sub.2 <- do.call(rbind, sub)      # join and return samples
    mean((sub.2$value))               # calculate the statistic
}


debugonce(boot)
set.seed(17); dat.boot <- boot(data = dat, statistic = resamp.mean, 4)


### stepping trough the debugger until object 'i' was assigned
### investigating 'i'
# Browse[2]> head(i)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
[1,]    3    7   12   13   10   14   14   15   12    12    12     4     5     9    10
[2,]   15    9    3   13    4   10    2    4    6    11    10     4     9     4     3
[3,]    8    4    7   15   10   12    9    8    9    12     4    15    14    10     4
[4,]   12    3    1   15    8   13    9    1    4    13     9    13     2    11     2

### which is not what I was hoping for.


### I would like something that looks like this, supposing indices = c(2, 2, 1) for the first resample: 

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
[1,]    6    7    8    9   10    6    7    8    9    10     1     2     3     4     5
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem originates from the modified statistic function (specifically, the `cls` object within the function). Can you try this one? Uncomment the `print` statement to see which subjects have been sampled. It does not use the `index` argument which `boot` expects, instead it just uses `sample` as in the original function.

```
resamp.mean <- function(dat, 
                        indices, 
                        cluster = c('subject', 'trial'), 
                        replace = TRUE){
      # boot expects an indices argument but the sampling happens
      # via sample() as in the original source of the function

      # sample the clustering factor
      cls <- sample(unique(dat[[cluster[1]]]), replace=replace)

      # subset on the sampled clustering factors
      sub <- lapply(cls, function(b) subset(dat, dat[[cluster[1]]]==b))

      # join and return samples
      sub <- do.call(rbind, sub)

      # UNCOMMENT HERE TO SEE SAMPLED SUBJECTS 
      # print(sub)

      mean(sub$value)
}
```

One resample from the `resamp.mean` function before the mean of `value` is calculated looks like this:

```
    trial subject      value
1       1       1 -1.1581291
2       2       1 -0.1458287
3       3       1 -0.2134525
4       4       1 -0.5796521
5       5       1  0.6501587
11      1       3  2.6678441
12      2       3  1.3945740
13      3       3  1.4849435
14      4       3  0.4086737
15      5       3  1.3399146
111     1       1 -1.1581291
121     2       1 -0.1458287
131     3       1 -0.2134525
141     4       1 -0.5796521
151     5       1  0.6501587
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Khl4v! The code you suggested seems to work fine. I've also check with `print(cls)` to see the various resampling of the clustering factor.
I didn't know you could "trick" the boot function by giving it an indicies argument but then not using it for the actual resampling. 
 Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed "tricking" the `boot` function. In certain cases the `strata` argument is the way to go, but I think it does not work for this specific application. There is another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615718/bootstrapping-to-compare-two-groups) on SO where someone at first tricked the function but then changed the solution to use `strata`.