# Confidence Interval from hierarchical bootstrap

Tags: r, statistics, hierarchical-data, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to calculate a BCa confidence interval for multi-stage bootstrap using `boot.ci()`. Here is an example from: [Non-parametric bootstrapping on the highest level of clustered data using boot() function from {boot} in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177270/non-parametric-bootstrapping-on-the-highest-level-of-clustered-data-using-boot)
which uses the `boot` command.

```
# creating example df
rho <- 0.4
dat <- expand.grid(
  trial=factor(1:5),
  subject=factor(1:3)
)
sig <- rho * tcrossprod(model.matrix(~ 0 + subject, dat))
diag(sig) <- 1
set.seed(17); dat$value <- chol(sig) %*% rnorm(15, 0, 1)

# function for resampling
resamp.mean <- function(dat, 
                    indices, 
                    cluster = c('subject', 'trial'), 
                    replace = TRUE){
  cls <- sample(unique(dat[[cluster[1]]]), replace=replace)
  sub <- lapply(cls, function(b) subset(dat, dat[[cluster[1]]]==b))
  sub <- do.call(rbind, sub)
  mean(sub$value)
} 

dat.boot <- boot(dat, resamp.mean, 4) # produces and estimated statistic

boot.ci(data.boot) # produces errors
```

How can I use `boot.ci` on the `boot` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used too few bootstrap resamples. When you call `boot.ci`, influence measures are needed, and if not provided they are obtained from `empinf`, which may fail with too few observations. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37918/why-is-the-error-estimated-adjustment-a-is-na-generated-from-r-boot-package) for an explanation along similar lines.

Try

```
dat.boot <- boot(dat, resamp.mean, 1000) 
boot.ci(dat.boot, type = "bca")
```

which gives:

```
> boot.ci(dat.boot, type = "bca") 

BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = dat.boot, type = "bca")

Intervals : 
Level       BCa          
95%   (-0.2894,  1.2979 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some BCa intervals may be unstable
```

As an alternative, you can provide `L` (the influence measures) yourself.

```
# proof of concept, use appropriate value for L!
> dat.boot <- boot(dat, resamp.mean, 4)
> boot.ci(dat.boot, type = "bca", L = 0.2)
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 4 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = dat.boot, type = "bca", L = 0.2)

Intervals : 
Level       BCa          
95%   ( 0.1322,  1.2979 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Warning : BCa Intervals used Extreme Quantiles
Some BCa intervals may be unstable
```

Comment: @coffeeinjunky Thank you! Don't I feel ridiculous that I spent so much time evaluating the code when the problem was so prosaic!

Comment: Glad I could help.