# Replace IDs with variables in bootstrapped samples to obtain 95% confidence intervals

Tags: r, matrix, difference, confidence-interval, bootstrapping

Hi I would like to calculate mean differences between two variables and their 95% bootstrapped confidence intervals from two data frames. I already constructed a matrix of bootstrapped samples, but not sure how to put the two variables in.

An example for the two data frames is as below:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Cost1 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
Gender <- c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M")

Cost2 <- c(400, 500, 600, 700, 700)

df1 <- data.frame(ID, Cost1, Gender)
df2 <- data.frame(ID, Cost2, Gender)
```

To make things easier, I only bootstrapped 3 times in this example. Each sample contains 5 IDs:

```
# Bootstrap
set.seed(1234)
n.c <- 5 # each sample contains 5 individuals
B <- 3 # bootstrap 3 times
Boot_ID <- matrix(sample(df1$ID, size = B*n.c, replace = T),
                  ncol = B, nrow = n.c)
```

I then obtained a matrix of IDs

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    4
[2,]    2    4    4
[3,]    5    2    5
[4,]    4    2    4
[5,]    1    4    3
```

Each column represents a sample. For example, the first sample (column 1) includes individual 4 two times, and then individuals 1, 2, and 5 only one time.

To calculate mean differences between `Cost1` and `Cost2` and the 95% confidence intervals for the differences, I'm thinking to generate two data frames by replacing these IDs with `Cost1` and `Cost2` separately, and then directly calculate the differences and the 95% bootstrapped confidence intervals. These two data frames will look like these:

```
#Dataframe_1 (replacing ID with Cost1)
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]  400  500  400
    [2,]  200  400  400
    [3,]  500  200  500
    [4,]  400  200  400
    [5,]  100  400  300

#Dataframe_2 (replacing ID with Cost2)
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]  700  800  700
    [2,]  500  700  700
    [3,]  800  500  800
    [4,]  700  500  700
    [5,]  400  700  600
```

However, I'm not sure how to replace these IDs with `Cost1` and `Cost2`. I would be really grateful if you can let me know how to do it. Also, I will be equally grateful if you tell me other more efficient ways to get 95% bootstrapped confidence intervals for differences between two variables.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not how you bootstrap the difference in means. You will typically draw N rows with replacement from your data.frame for each of the two "grouping" factors (cost1 or cost 2). This can be done with 1 or 2 data.frames, doesn't matter. You then estimate the mean for each group and take the difference. This is then one bootstrap iteration. Repeat this as many times as desired. Looks like an XY problem where the actual question is how to bootstrap. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrapping to compare two groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615718/bootstrapping-to-compare-two-groups)

Comment: @socialscientist Thanks a lot. I think I might not be clear in the question. I'm interested in the difference between Cost1 and Cost2 for each individual, not the difference in means in the two groups. It is therefore crucial for me to keep the same IDs across the two groups. I think, alternatively, I may just derive a column of differences between Cost1 and Cost2 for each individual, and then simply bootstrap those differences?

Comment: If you are not clear in the question, make the question clear.